# Sending http only cookie in Authorization header django-rest-framework

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, cookie-httponly, django-rest-knox

I'm building a rest API using `django-rest-framework` with auth implementation with `django-rest-knox` and I want to store the token in an http only cookie with a React frontend. So I've used thie code:

```
from django.contrib.auth import login
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.authtoken.serializers import AuthTokenSerializer
from knox.views import LoginView as KnoxLoginView


class LoginView(KnoxLoginView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AuthTokenSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        user = serializer.validated_data['user']
        login(request, user)
        response = super(LoginView, self).post(request, format=None)

        token = response.data['token']
        del response.data['token']

        response.set_cookie(
            'auth_token',
            token,
            httponly=True,
            samesite='strict'
        )

        return response
```

from this topic [django-rest-knox with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54753034/django-rest-knox-with-cookies)

This code use the Set-Cookie Header and it works but the problem is when I want to request in a protected route I need the token for the Authorization header, so how can I do it.

Comment: I'm running into the same problem, except using a SvelteKit frontend. How can you access the token from the client to send it to the server in the Authorization header?